# Compare two lists

Tags: java, collections

I want to compare two lists. Since we code to interface using `List`, which does not inherit the `equals` from  from the Object class. How do I do this?

Comment: Every implementation of List does directly or indirectly inherit from Object. Sounds like you got some misunderstandings of OO here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even though the `List` interface does not contain an `equals` method, the list-classes may (and does) still implement the `equals` method.

From the [API docs on `AbstractList`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) (inherited by for instance `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `Vector`):

> **`public boolean equals(Object o)`**
>
> > Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal.

The same applies to for instance the `toString`, `hashCode` method and so on.

---

As @Pascal mentions in the comments, the List interface mentions the `equals` method and states the following in the documentation:

> The List interface places additional stipulations, beyond those specified in the Collection interface, on the contracts of the iterator, add, remove, equals, and hashCode methods.

Comment: I realize I wasn't clear and you are correct (and so does the answer now).

Answer (score 3):

It's the usual story: you have to consider "shallow equals" and "deep equals".

The default behavior that you get out of java.lang.Object is "shallow equals".  It'll check to see if list1 and list2 are the same references:

```
List list1 = new ArrayList();
List list2 = list1;

list1.equals(list2); // returns true;
```

If you want "deep equals", instantiate anything that extends AbstractList, such as ArrayList.

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

list1.add("hello");
list2.add("hello");
System.out.println(list1.equals(list2)); // will print true

list1.add("foo");
list2.add("bar");
System.out.println(list1.equals(list2)); // will print false
```

Comment: According to the [Lists.equals() JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), implementations of the `List` interface must check equality element by element. So even though `Object.equals()` does "shallow equals", `List.equals()` (and any conforming implementation) does "deep equals", and there is no need to write your own method.

Comment: Agreed about List, but if the element doesn't override equals you don't get "deep equals".  It's not worded very clearly, but I believe that's the truth.

Comment: Object.equals() is just a placeholder for deep equals; it is not meant to be used for shallow equals.  The standard contract requires that every object (not just List) implements equals() to do deep equality.  That's what the equals() method is for.  '==' is for shallow comparison.

Comment: Sorry, the default implementation in java.lang.Object is shallow equals.  That's what you get if you do nothing.   This answer is FOUR YEARS OLD.  You add nothing with this useless comment.  Go do something else, like answer a question, to boost your reputation.

Comment: The above example was trying to instantiate an interface.   Changed to actually make it compile.

Comment: @duffymo I have the 2 lists and both are exactly same but still the list1.equals(list2) returns me false .Can you please help ?

Comment: What class type do the lists hold?  My guess is that you didn't implement equals and hashCode for that class.  This answer is eight years old.  Ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `equals`. All objects implement it, and your lists are still objects and override `equals` as you need it.